# Java most specific method subtyping rules

Tags: java, language-lawyer, jls

In [§15.12.2.5](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.12.2.5) of the Java Language Specification they describe how Java chooses the most specific method to call from a list of both *accessible* and *applicable* methods.

There is one specific remark that I don't understand, namely:

> (1) A type **S** is *more specific* than a type **T** for any expression
>   if **S <: T**

The part that really bothers me is *"any expression"*.

To give an example why, I'll be quoting the previous paragraph that says when given two methods m<sub>1</sub> and m<sub>2</sub> we can say m<sub>1</sub> is *more specific* than  m<sub>2</sub> for an invocation with argument expressions e<sub>1</sub>, ..., e<sub>k</sub> if:

> m<sub>2</sub> is not generic, and m<sub>1</sub> and m<sub>2</sub> are applicable by strict or loose
>   invocation, and where m<sub>1</sub> has formal parameter types S<sub>1</sub>, ..., S<sub>n</sub> and m<sub>2</sub>
>   has formal parameter types T<sub>1</sub>, ..., T<sub>n</sub>, the type S<sub>i</sub> is more specific
>   than T<sub>i</sub> for argument e<sub>i</sub> for all i (1 ≤ i ≤ n, n = k).

So if the type S<sub>i</sub> (m<sub>1</sub>) is more specific than T<sub>i</sub> (m<sub>2</sub>) with argument expression e<sub>i</sub> for all i, then m<sub>1</sub> is *more specific* than m<sub>2</sub>

Now consider this:

```
int a(Number a) { return 1; } // m1
int a(Double a) { return 2; } // m2
```

Since `Double <: Number` it follows that for any expression `Double` is more specific than `Number` (from quote 1).

We have:

m<sub>1</sub> : S<sub>1</sub> => Number

m<sub>2</sub> : T<sub>1</sub> => Double

But then if our argument argument expression e<sub>1</sub> is of type `Number` m<sub>2</sub> is the most specific method since `Double` is most specific for **any** expression (quote 1).

However, if we pass in a `Number` to `a()` the result is `1` ie. the method taking a `Double` is not chosen. But quote 1 says that if `Double` is a subtype of `Number` for any expression `Double` will be more specific, so how come it chooses `a(Number)`?

What am I missing here?

**Note**:
I know `Number` is not assignable to `Double` and it wouldn't make sense for the compiler to choose the other one, I'm just trying to see what I'm mis-interpreting from the first quote.

Comment: This confuses me. You already quoted "and *applicable*" and then you wonder why the method with the non-applicable parameter type isn't chosen even though it has the more specific type and would have been used ***if*** it were applicable? What? `a(Double)` isn't usabe if you pass `Number`, there is nothing more here to tell.

Comment: @Tom Oh my god. I went through all the trouble of trying to understand this when the basic premise was false. I assumed it was applicable the whole time. Thanks a lot!

Comment: You can rethink these rules with other types, like `Double`, `Integer` and `null` (just for the heck of it :D). And maybe some primitives, too. That might be interessting.

Comment: IMHO more important is that the decision is made at *compile time*, not at runtime.

Comment: @Tom Yes I will, I just misinterpreted reference widening and assumed it was applicable just because they sat on the same inheritance tree

Answer (score 0):

It turns out my misunderstanding was not as part of the quote but as to what an **applicable** function would be under *loose* or *strict* invocation.

More specifically *strict/loose* invocation contexts allow a set of conversions

- An identity conversion ie. `Number` to `Number`
- A widening primitive conversion ie. `byte to short,int,long,float or double`
- A widening reference conversion ie. `Double` to `Number`
- A boxing conversion ie. `int to Integer` optionally followed by a widening reference conversion
- An unboxing conversion ie. `Integer to int` optionally followed by a widening primitive conversion

In my example, I overlooked the fact that a *widening reference conversion* cannot be applied to `Number` because `Number` is not a subtype of `Double` hence `int a(Double a)` is not considered an applicable method.